# Ask syslog which log files it uses for which facilities

Tags: syslog

Regarding the manpage of `syslog` there are different *facilities* (e.g. `USER`). Depending on that facility log messages going into different log files (e.g. `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, ...).

I assume this is not 100% equal between all existing unixoid (or GNU/Linux based) distributions. Can I ask a running `syslog` instance which log files it currently use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ask a `syslog` instance anything. However, you can look at its configuration file. The documentation for your particular implementation of `syslog` will tell you the file name (see `man syslogd` if you're really running vanilla `syslog`).

- `syslogd` - `/etc/syslog.conf`
- `rsyslogd` - `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and files under `/etc/rsyslog.d/`

(Probably others.)

If you're on a Linux-based system then there's the whole `systemd` experience with `journalctl` and friends, too.

Comment: That's okay, "asking" syslog/rsyslog/syslog-ng what logfiles it writes is accomplished by querying its config file by means of `cat` or `grep`.  ;)